# Checking if a number is a Happy Prime Number

Tags: java, math, primes

I have written a code which is used to check whether a number is happy prime number or not. Happy numbers are [these types of numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)

Here is an example of a happy number:

[image]

In the end we are getting "1" that means it is a happy prime.

Found my mistake, Thanks to @resueman But still there is one problem.
It is not printing the output of the fourth input that is "4 1000"

The new code is:

```
   import java.io.*;

public class Contest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        for(int m =n; m>0; m--)
        {
            String s = reader.readLine();
            String[] sa = s.split(" ");
            String number = sa[1];
            int squareNumber;
            int orignialNum = Integer.parseInt(number);

            boolean isPrime = true;
            for(int i=2; i<=orignialNum/2;i++)
            {
                if(orignialNum % i == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                }

            }
            if(isPrime)
            {
                if(orignialNum == 0 || orignialNum == 1 || orignialNum == 2 || orignialNum == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println(sa[0]+" "+orignialNum+" "+"No");
                }
                else
                {
                    squareNumber = orignialNum;
                    if(orignialNum<10){
                        squareNumber = orignialNum*orignialNum;
                    }

                    int newNumber = check(squareNumber);


                    boolean isHappyNumber = isHappy(newNumber);
                    if(isHappyNumber)
                    {
                        System.out.println(sa[0]+" "+orignialNum+" "+"Yes");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(sa[0]+" "+orignialNum+" "+"No");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(sa[0]+" "+orignialNum+" "+"No");
            }

        }

}
public static boolean isHappy(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public static int check(int n)
{
        if(n>9)
        {
            String sm = String.valueOf(n);
            String[] m = sm.split("");
            int[] a = new int[m.length];
            for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++)
            {
                a[i]= Integer.parseInt(m[i]);

            }

            for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++)
            {
                a[i]= a[i]*a[i];

            }
            int sum = 0;

            for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++)
            {
                sum = sum+a[i];
            }
            return check(sum);
        }
        else
        {
            return n;
        }
}
}
```

The first line will take the number of input it will take when executed.

The input I am giving is:

```
4
1 1
2 7
3 383
4 1000
```

The output I am getting:

```
1 1 No
2 7 Yes
3 383 No
```

And the expected output is:

```
1 1 NO
2 7 YES
3 383 YES
4 1000 NO
```

Somehow the 4th output is not appearing and for "383" it is 
showing no.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you square the number before checking happiness? Is this what makes it "happy happy"?

Comment: You need to be checking the sum of the square of the digits. Not the *square* of the sum of the square of the digits. For your second problem, it goes through all four when I run it.

Comment: What is a happy happy prime? Is it a happy prime which is also happy, because that is just a happy prime.

Comment: @Henry I have to do it because this is the first step for checking happiness. The answer I received from square will be used to checking the happiness as there square will be added.

Comment: No, not according to the link you posted.

Comment: @resueman But, I am checking the sum of the square of the digits. I am not using the square of the sum of the digit

Comment: @Henry Check this [link](http://s15.postimg.org/ko3s52gij/Capture.png) In the end we are getting one that means its a happy prime

Comment: @Raddix, You do `int squareNum = originalNum * originalNum; check(squareNum)`. Since `check` computes the sum of the squares, squaring it beforehand computes the square of the sum of the square of the digits, which is not what the article says you need.

Comment: @resueman Sorry for the confusion, I have added a link which contains one example of this problem. The link is [this](http://s15.postimg.org/ko3s52gij/Capture.png)

Comment: @Raddix That example still doesn't square the number first though; It's just the first repetition of squaring the digits. Since it's only digit is `7` it's the same as squaring the entire thing, but that will stop working once there's more than 1 digit.

Comment: @resueman Your name should be rescueMan. Yes you are right that is my mistake. But there is still one more problem. When I am inputting all the given inputs as above, its still not printing the results for "4 1000"

Comment: @Raddix I copied and pasted your code, and that input is going through all four when I test it. Are you sure you're entering the input correctly? I just tried your updated code as well, and it prints out all four answers.

Comment: If you've got a solution to this, post it as an answer.  Don't edit your question with the new code.

Comment: @resueman I am using this code in Hackerrank and they put all the input at once. If you copy and paste all the input and paste it at once then it should produce that output. But at Hackerran the only output I am getting is "1 1 No" and When I am using this in eclipse then I am getting all the output except the last one.

Comment: @Raddix Then sorry, but I can't help. I've tried typing it in line by line, redirecting the input from a file, and passing it all at once, and each one gives all four outputs for me.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry I am new and I don't know the rules

Comment: The idea of stackoverflow is, that other people can profit from your question. If you're overwriting your question with the answer, nobody can see the initial question. Post your solution as an answer instead.

Comment: @brimborium So, Sorry for that I won't do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code a little and came up with this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int numInputs = 0;
        BufferedReader reader;

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        numInputs = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        for(; numInputs > 0; numInputs -= 1) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
            int number = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]);

            if(isPrime(number)) {
                if(number == 2 || number == 3) {
                    System.out.format("%s %d No\n", splitLine[0], number);
                } else {
                    if(isHappy(number)) {
                        System.out.format("%s %d Yes\n", splitLine[0], number);
                    } else {
                        System.out.format("%s %d No\n", splitLine[0], number);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s %d No\n", splitLine[0], number);
            }

        }

    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) return false;
        if (n == 2 || n == 3) return true;

        if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        // If multiple of 2 or 3 it's not a prime
            return false;
        }

        // Search for divisors from 5 to only sqrt(n)
        // Example: 36: (1*36) (2*18) (3*12) (6*6) (12*3) (18*2) (36*1)
        for ( int i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6 ) {
            // Check only odd numbers
            if ( n % i == 0 || n % ( i + 2 ) == 0 ) {
                // i+4 is not checked cause it's a multiple of 3
                // i is increased by 6 (multiple of 3) and the first i+4 = 9
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isHappy(int n) {
        do {
            int sum = 0;

            // While number n has two or more digits
            while( n / 10 != 0 ) { 
                int remainder = n % 10;         // last digit
                n = n / 10;                     // n without last digit
                sum += remainder * remainder;
            }
            sum += n * n;                       // add square of the last digit
            n = sum;
        } while(n != 1 && n != 4);              // n == 1 => :) n == 4 => :(

        return n == 1;
    }
}
```